Integration of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ax}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx$
I have to solve the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ax} \cdot e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx$$
I have no idea how to do this. I don't understand how you can integrate by parts if the antiderivative of the second term is not defined. I tried to have a look on the other answers on the forum for the Gaussian, but none of them helped me... Maybe I need polar coordinates?

Hint: write the integrand in the form $\exp\left(b-\frac{(x-c)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ for some $b,,c$, then substitute $z=\frac{x-c}{\sigma}$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112327/1163258.

$$\int e^{ax}e^{-\frac{(x-μ)^2}{2σ^2}}dx=\int e^{\frac{[x-(μ-aσ^2)]^2}{2σ^2}}e^{\frac{μ^2-(μ-aσ^2)^2}{2σ^2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2πσ}}{\sqrt{2πσ}}\int e^{\frac{[x-(μ-aσ^2)]^2}{2σ^2}}e^{\frac{μ^2-(μ-aσ^2)^2}{2σ^2}}dx =\sqrt{2πσ}
e^{\frac{μ^2-(μ-aσ^2)^2}{2σ^2}}$$

I believe you are looking for the Moment generating function for a normal distribution,
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ax}  e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx$$
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2+2ax\sigma^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx$$
$$I={e^{\mu a +\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2a^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   e^{\frac{-(x-(\mu+\sigma^2a))^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx$$
The integral evaluates to 1,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   e^{\frac{-(x-(\mu+\sigma^2a))^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx=1$$
$$I= \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma \,
e^{\mu a +\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2a^2}$$

$$\exp \left(ax-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma ^{2}} \right) = \exp \left(ax-\frac{x^2-2x \mu + \mu^{2}}{2 \sigma ^{2}} \right) = \exp \left(\frac{-x^2+2( \mu +a \sigma^{2})x - \mu^{2}}{2 \sigma ^{2}} \right)$$
$$=\exp \left(\frac{-x^2+2( \mu +a \sigma^{2})x -\mu^{2}\color{red}{-a^2\sigma^4-2a\mu\sigma^2}\color{blue}{+a^2\sigma^4+2a\mu\sigma^2}}{2 \sigma ^{2}} \right)$$
$$=\exp \left(-\frac{(x-\mu-a\sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{a^2 \sigma^2}{2}+a\mu \right)$$ $$=\left[\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu-a\sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right]\exp\left(\frac{a^2 \sigma^2}{2}+a\mu \right)\color{red}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
Note that the first term is the probability distribution function of a Normal distribution with mean $\mu+a\sigma^2$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, hence its integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$.
Hence, our required integral $$\boxed{I=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{a^2 \sigma^2}{2}+a\mu \right)}$$
